# write attribute_line_ids in product.tempate in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

i am getting fields data from xls file and creating product
everything work fine except one2many field of variant in product.template
how can i achieve this.
here is my code.

```
main_product = self.env["product.template"].create(product_data)

attribute_ids = self.env["product.attribute"].search([])
attrib_id_set = set(ids.name for ids in attribute_ids)
product_attrib_ids = sheet.cell(suits, 13).value.split(",")

attrib_id_list = []; exist_attribute_list = []
for name in product_attrib_ids:
    if name not in attrib_id_set:
        attrib_id = self.env["product.attribute"].create({'name':name})
        attrib_id_list.append(attrib_id)
    else:
        exist_attribute = self.env["product.attribute"].search([('name','=',name)])
        exist_attribute_list.append(exist_attribute)

union_list = list(set(attrib_id_list).union(exist_attribute_list))

exist_attribute_values = self.env["product.attribute.value"].search([])
exist_attrib_val_list = [attrib_name.name for attrib_name in exist_attribute_values]

product_attrib_id_values = sheet.cell(suits, 14).value.split(",")
for value in product_attrib_id_values:
    if value not in exist_attrib_val_list:
        for ids in union_list:
            attrib_value_id = self.env["product.attribute.value"].create({
                'attribute_id':ids.id,
                'name':value
            })
            main_product.write({
                'attribute_line_ids':[(0,0,{
                    'attribute_id':ids.id, 'value_ids':(4,attrib_value_id.id)
                 })]
            })
```

**product_data** is my dictionary for fields like name,sale_ok,type,catag_id etc.
this works, product is created, attribute_id and attribute values even works
but i can not write one2many of variant in product.template.

**--EDIT--**

```
values_lst=[]
for value in product_attrib_id_values:
    if value not in exist_attrib_val_list:
        for ids in union_list:
            attrib_value_id = self.env["product.attribute.value"].create({
                'attribute_id':ids.id,
                'name':value
            })
    else:
        for ids in exist_attribute_values:
            if value == ids.name:
                attrib_value_id =self.env["product.attribute.value"].browse(ids.id)
                if attrib_value_id not in values_lst:
                    values_lst.append(attrib_value_id)
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log?

Comment: i changed a little in main_product.write, i have passed attribute id for many2one and (4,id) for many2many. it gave me odoo server error "You cannot use this attribute with the following value. "

Comment: There is a constraint on `(attributes_id, value_ids)`, Odoo will raise a validation error if the following expression is evaluated to `True`: **any(not line.value_ids or line.value_ids > line.attribute_id.value_ids for line in self)**

Comment: i tried to create product with attribute value, this creates a product in product.product with attribute value, it fills it with many2many for attribute value but if i have more than one attribute value it took only one value.

Comment: Correct `value_ids` to `'value_ids':[(4,attrib_value_id.id)]`